# Linker command failed with exit code 1; undefined symbols for architecture armv7s.

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, app-store, ipa

This is a first time I've been trying to upload binary (new version of an iOS App, not a completely new app) to the iTunes store. When I attempt to create an archive, I receive three `Apple Mach-o linker errors`, which show up red in issue navigator.

This is what shows up:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/alinam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Latina_1-bklvousdwnrhhgenrxpftegwerkb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Latina 1/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/alinam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Latina_1-bklvousdwnrhhgenrxpftegwerkb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Latina 1/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o`


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
```

In one of the existing discussions I read that it might have something to do with linking binary with libraries.

Well, under `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries the libCordova.a shows up red (missing?)`.

If so, how and where do I get it and what do I do with it then?

**Update:**

I resolved the issue of not being able to archive the app by removing `armv7s` and `arm64` (and leaving only `armv7`) in the app's `Build Settings -> Architectures -> Valid Architectures`.

Now it looks like [this](http://i243.photobucket.com/albums/ff92/gimlins555/latina_architectures_zpsdcfc0b57.png).

I've left everything as it was under `CordovaLib.xcodeproj -> Build Settings -> Architectures`, which looks like [this](http://i243.photobucket.com/albums/ff92/gimlins555/cordova_architectures_zpsac9a9c77.png).

So I have a new question: can I really simply remove `armv7s` and `arm64` from Valid Architectures without any consequences? Will the app run on all the devices it should? In all the related discussions I've read through I couldn't find a definite answer to this.

Comment: I run into the same problem, and now Apple sent me a message like this: "Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code." every time I upload a new version to the AppStore. Some knows how to fix it?