# Xcode 6 linker error - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linker, upgrade

After upgrading to Xcode 6 beta 7 (and now still with Xcode 6 GM) I am unable to link my Swift app. I receive errors such as:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_swift_stdlib_compareNSStringDeterministicUnicodeCollation", referenced from:
>
> ...
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have seen the other SO posts that recommend deleting the Derived Data folder and/or using the Clean Build Folder option to get past this error, but that solution didn't help at all in my case. Nothing has changed about my code or the CocoaPods I'm using since Xcode 6 beta 5 which is the last time it worked.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

A full posting of the error log:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_swift_stdlib_compareNSStringDeterministicUnicodeCollation", referenced from:
>         **TFC12MyProject21BarcodeViewController13captureOutputfS0_FTGSQCSo15AVCaptureOutput_24didOutputMetadataObjectsGSQGSaPSs9AnyObject___14fromConnectionGSQCSo19AVCaptureConnection__T_ in BarcodeViewController.o
>     "__TFSs21_arrayConditionalCastU___FGSaQ__GSqGSaQ0_**", referenced from:
>         **TFC12MyProject27SessionsTableViewController17viewWillDisappearfS0_FSbT_ in SessionsTableViewController.o
>     "__TFSs15_arrayForceCastU___FGSaQ__GSaQ0**", referenced from:
>         __TFC12MyProject7RestApi12tokenMappingfS0_FT_CSo15RKEntityMapping in RestApi.o
>         __TFC12MyProject28AttendeesTableViewControllerg24fetchedResultsControllerCSo26NSFetchedResultsController in AttendeesTableViewController.o
>         __TFC12MyProject27SessionsTableViewControllerg24fetchedResultsControllerCSo26NSFetchedResultsController in SessionsTableViewController.o
>         __TFC12MyProject21BarcodeViewController13startScanningfS0_FT_Sb in BarcodeViewController.o
>     "__TFSs26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCU__FTPSs9AnyObject_MQ__Q_", referenced from:
>         __TFC12MyProject7RestApi12resetRestKitfS0_FT_T_ in RestApi.o
>         __TFC12MyProject16BluetoothManager17_startAdvertisingfS0_FT_T_ in BluetoothManager.o
>         __TFC12MyProject19LoginViewController32registerForKeyboardNotificationsfS0_FT_T_ in LoginViewController.o
>         __TFC12MyProject19LoginViewController35deregisterFromKeyboardNotificationsfS0_FT_T_ in LoginViewController.o
>         __TFC12MyProject19LoginViewController16callProcessLoginfS0_FT_T_ in LoginViewController.o
>         __TFC12MyProject21CheckinViewController16enableBeaconModefS0_FT_T_ in CheckinViewController.o
>         __TFC12MyProject21BarcodeViewController13startScanningfS0_FT_Sb in BarcodeViewController.o
>         ...
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Silly one but have you rebooted?

Comment: Well, no. Guess I'll try that.

Comment: I am getting this and I still have beta 5 installed - the same project builds fine in beta 5 with no code changes, even after making some changes for the recent swift updates.

Comment: Did you try to create new project in xCode6GM and run some basic scenario?  The only one thing that was different from Betas was playground structure so I deleted and created new ones.

Comment: Im not iOS guru, anyways i had similar problem when migrated from beta 5 to 6. Try to play with Code signing, clear all fields and choose again

Comment: Have you done all the steps described [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583690/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7) ?

Comment: Can you post the line from the build log where this error is reported? It will tell you what specific library it is having trouble with.

Comment: @quellish I added a full log entry.

Comment: Cool. It's only this project, right? You don't see the same thing when you create a new swift project as a test?

Comment: @quellish, correct. New projects work fine. I suppose I can just create a new project and migrate all my files over. :(

Comment: That will probably be the fastest way to move forward. I suspect I know what the problem is, but can't be sure. If you can, zip up the project and submit a bug on it. Was the project file under source control?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What's happening here has nothing to do with your Derived Data location.

When a swift application is built, it goes through several steps:

- Write auxiliary files
- Create product structure
- Compile swift source for each architecture
- Copy resource rules plist
- Copy application bridging header
- Link against swift runtime libraries for each architecture
- Copy application swift module for each architecture
- Create the application binary
- Copy resources build phase
- Copy the swift standard libraries into the application
- Package it up
- Sign it

Whew! That's a lot. Your build is failing when linking against the swift runtime libraries. They live in `Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos` inside the Xcode developer directory. Specifically, the library that is not being correctly linked is `libswiftCore.dylib`. If you use `nm` on that library, you can see it defines your first missing symbol:

```
quellish% nm /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib | grep compareNSStringDeterministicUnicodeCollation
00197c8c T _swift_stdlib_compareNSStringDeterministicUnicodeCollation
000000000018352c T _swift_stdlib_compareNSStringDeterministicUnicodeCollation
```

You can also use `lipo` to see what architectures are in the file:

```
quellish% xcrun lipo -info /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib
Architectures in the fat file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib are: armv7 arm64
```

It contains armv7 and arm64. It's not the library architecture that's the problem.

Linking against the swift standard library is not working. It's possible that source control or migrating Xcode versions has caused your project file to drop part of the linking step, or it's simply not able to find the libraries it needs to link against. Xcode project files are complex and use a lot of references - it's possible that a merge, etc. caused a critical reference to be come dissociated from the linking step. Without a full build log and a look at your machine it may not be possible to tell.

This library, as you might guess, has nothing to do with the project's derived data location.

The best way to move forward would unfortunately be to recreate the project file. Comparing the build log of the broken project to a swift project that does build correctly may provide some insights, but it may also be a waste of time - something fixable may be the problem, but more likely not.

I would encourage you to file a bug and include the troublesome project file with it.

Comment: This was the information I needed. I knew it had nothing to do with DerivedData which is why I created this question in the first place. There were already plenty of SO answers regarding the DerivedData problem. Rather than trying to pore over all the build logs and settings and figure out what got dropped I'm moving forward with recreated the project and moving my code into it. When I have the time I'll try to compare the diffs between the two projects. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a followup for anyone tracking... I rebuilt my project from scratch and copied over all my settings and code. It builds just fine now. No amount of cleaning derived data ever helped and I tried a LOT of permutations of the concept. So as quellish said, the problem really had nothing to do with the derived data, but was something internal to this project that couldn't be easily cleaned or wiped away. At least I'm back in action now.

Comment: Did you ever diff the projects?

Answer (score 11):

I have solved my issue by deleting all the data in the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder. I read about that in another thread, but ignored it thinking a clean included that process!

Comment: I started getting linker errors after upgrading the Xcode to Xcode 6 GM Seed, and clearing this folder out resolved the errors.

Comment: I've already deleted all the data in that folder. I first cleaned the project. Then I exited Xcode and deleted the DerivedData folder. Then I relaunched Xcode and built the app. Same error.

Answer (score 8):

I have Updated on Yosemite, Xcode 6.1.
I have updated gem xcodeproj (0.19.4) and cocoapods (0.34.4).

I have resolve my conflict by :

Clearing the Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder

replace in Target -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags : $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)

Check in Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Pods Resources : "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"

Comment: This made no difference for me :(

Answer (score 3):

1) I face the same problem but just clear the applications from derived data from `User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and I am able to run the code.

2) In your case may be, it will run by removing armv7 architecture from build settings. And make sure your compiler is Default Compiler in Build Settings.

Thanks I hope this helpful to you and everyone.

Comment: Dropping armv7 is not really an option because I need to support the iPhone 4s. I tried dropping it just to see and then it failed with arm64.

Comment: Yes you are right, is there any .a file in your project? because perhaps that .a file is not a compilation of armv7 and arm64. and take look in your error symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused (for most) by linking a third-party library that does not support the requested architecture.

Comment: I removed all my pods and I was still getting this issue.

Comment: I'm with you, @BradR, it appears to happen no matter what. The linker errors occur even when referencing only Apple frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat similar problem (a linker error from Apple's framework). As it turned out, the problem was that I was missing the library LocalAuthentication.framework. I am wondering if maybe you need to delete the Foundation.framework from the Build Phase tab (in the Link Libraries section), and then re-add it? Maybe that will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

'Upgraded' to xcode 6 and swift app wouldn't build for simulator yet would build fine on an iPad - Linker error, undefined symbols for i386 for the simulator.

Clearing the Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in Xcode 6.0.1 that is causing the linker to drop dependencies in existing project files. I have had this same problem across several different projects, new and old, since the 6.0.1 update.

The easy 'fix' is to just trash your entire 'Derrived Data' and all build files (i.e. manually clean the project) and then rebuild after a fresh Xcode restart. Magically, the linker now finds all the missing architectures/symbols.

NOTE: I have had several incompatible v-table crashes caused by this same bug. The C++ linker appears to be generating incomplete linkages, causing absurd errors where there are no *real* errors to be found. Again, just rebuild from a clean state and .. ta da.. save yourself a LOT of headache and wasted time tracking down a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue after trying all that was suggested here with no luck.
Like someone said earlier, it's a SourceControl issue.

One of my project files (the one referenced in the error message) was missing from the project browser. However, XCode still had a reference to it (I was going to the class definition when I was selecting "jump to definition" from Xcode GUI).

As a matter of fact, the project.pbxproj was not listing it. This was probably a Git Issue. In any event, I just recreated the file in the same directory it has been recreated and voila.

Answer (score 0):

I am a filly when it comes to iOS Objective C, though I have been coding in several other languages for many years. So I am stabbing around in the dark most of the time with Objective C.

I started having this error, "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7", directly after declaring some "global" variables in my .h file like so:

```
extern NSString *globalNotes;
extern NSString *globalUserCountry;
```

I was then referring to these variables from the .m file like so:

```
globalNotes= @"Error (Marker 1010)";
globalUserCountry= @"No result";
```

THE FIX - To correct this, I changed them to object properties like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *globalNotes;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *globalUserCountry;
```

And referred to them like so:

```
self.globalNotes= @"Error (Marker 1010)";
self.globalUserCountry= @"No result";
```

That seemed to fix my problem.