# VR One demo build errors for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, vrone

I'm having troubles with creating a build for iPhone. I can make a build in Unity to be used with Xcode, but building in Xcode for iPhone gives me the following five errors.

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_SCNMatrix4MakeRotation", referenced from:
>       __GetQuaternionUpdate in libVROneHeadTracking.a(RotateAround.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNNode", referenced from:
>       objc-class-ref in libVROneHeadTracking.a(RotateAround.o)
>   "_SCNMatrix4Invert", referenced from:
>       __GetQuaternionUpdate in libVROneHeadTracking.a(RotateAround.o)
>   "_SCNMatrix4Mult", referenced from:
>       __GetQuaternionUpdate in libVROneHeadTracking.a(RotateAround.o)
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

It is all related to libVROneHeadTracking.a, so I can't open it. Am I doing something wrong or is there an error in this file?

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? I found this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765352/xcode-6-linker-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the fix! LOL, for me, I was just being super lazy and forgot to add SceneKit.

Unity-iPhone -> Build Phase -> Link Binary With Libraries

Hit the '+' sign and add SceneKit framework.

clean, and build and it should work.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. I now see that it was indeed mentioned at the requirements section. It is SceneKit framework by the way, not SpriteKit. I think this should also be noted at the getting started section.